# Groovydoc: Documenting named parameters

Tags: groovy, code-documentation, groovydoc

I've created a method like so:

```
void myMethod(Map kwArgs, def myParam)
{
   println kwArgs.firstName
   println [kwArgs.lastName, "Wilcox"].find()  
   // ^^^ if lastName named parameter not specified, "Wilcox"

   ....
}
```

Now comes the time to document this method with GroovyDoc. Part of it is easy

```
/**
  myMethod rules the world
  @param myParam something something
```

But how do I document the named parameters? (Likewise, how can I specify that the `lastName` parameter has a default? (ie is there some metadata I can set or just make that explicit to the reader in the English description?)

Comment: I think you just have to make it explicit, maybe with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I document the named parameters?

Unless you are considering writing a customer doclet or similar, I think you will just document them as text in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have adopted a pattern that uses `<dl>` in the documentation comment, and re-assignment for clarity (and inspection?):

```
/**
 * Nothing to see here
 *
 * @param kvargs <dl>
 *     <dt>{@code foo: String}</dt>
 *     <dd>
 *         The root of it all<br />
 *         <em>Default:</em> {@code bar}
 *     </dd>
 *
 *     <dt>{@code baristas: List<String>}</dt>
 *     <dd>
 *         Whom to blame<br />
 *         <em>Default:</em> {@code []}
 *     </dd>
 * </dl>
 */
void example(@Nonnull Map kvargs = [:]) {
    def foo = kvargs.foo?.toString() ?: 'bar'
    def baristas = (kvargs.baristas ?: []) as List<String>

    doThings(foo, baristas)
}
```

I haven't rendered it as HTML, but the output is good enough in IDEA:
[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA quick-doc rendered from above code]

Explicitly accessing all args seems to have the benefit of enabling limited syntax completion:
[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA completing parameters of method example, given a matching prefix]
But, alas, the documentation is not displayed (unsurprisingly)
No list of possible parameters is provided, either:
[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA parameter list for method example]